# How do I make an exception for a blank space so it would not output a 0?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

How do I make an exception for blank spaces so it would not ouput 0. It's only outputting the "total" itself.

```
 line = input("Enter a line of numbers - separate them with spaces: ")
    strings = line.split()
    total = 0
    try:
        for substr in strings:
            total += float(substr)
        print("The total is:", total)
    except:
        print(substr, "is not a number.")
```

Comment: What problem do you face? `str.split()` will treat consecutive whitespaces as one. Your code works for me, although blank `except` is discouraged. post [mre], no input from from user and post full traceback if you get any. And fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# line = input("Enter a line of numbers - separate them with spaces: ")
line = '1 1 b 1 1 11 1 666'
strings = line.split()
total = 0

for substr in strings:
    try:
        total += float(substr)
    except:
        print(substr, "is not a number.")
print("The total is:", total)
```

or

```
for substr in strings:
    if substr.isnumeric():
        total += float(substr)
print("The total is:", total)
```